# conversion of job responsibilites and requirements from job descriptions to skillset Using Nlp

Tags: python, nlp, deep-learning, nltk

I am working on a NLP problem of rewriting job responsibilities and requirements to skill sets ready to be mentioned in the resume.
Example:
1:responsibility:

"Train, supervise, motivate and develop sales personnel to attain or exceed their sales territory sales goals;"

1:skill:
"Have provided training,guidance and motivation to 
sales representatives to achieve or exceed their sales area and target."

I have tried to do this using paraphrasing techniques,but the narration of sentence and some words are not appropriate to be mentioned in resume.

Any help and guidance will be appreciable.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use POS tagging / Parse Trees to take the corpus of job responsibility sentences that you have accumulated and split it into some broad categories.
(e.g. sentences that start out with a bunch of comma-separated verbs, sentences that have a single verb but are in the past tense (i.e. requiring the person to have some specific type of experience), etc).

Now try to create a transformation rule for each of those parts.

The rule for the sentence you put above might be to prefix the sentence with the word "Can".

Some rules might require to change the tense of some verb, convert some noun from singular to plural, swap the order of some parts of the sentence, etc. All these things should be doable using standard NLP tools.